# Is there a more efficient way of doing this code without if statements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have made this code that uses the set interval function to go through an array.

```
<img src="red.jpg" id="traffic" width="155" height="198">

<script>

var imgarray = ["red.jpg", "redandorange.jpg", "green.jpg", "orange.jpg"]
document.getElementById("traffic").innerHTML = traffic;

setInterval(function () {
ChangeLights() ;
}, 2000) ;

function ChangeLights() { 
if (traffic.src.match(imgarray[0])){
traffic.src = imgarray[1];
}else if (traffic.src.match(imgarray[1])){
traffic.src = imgarray[2];
}else if (traffic.src.match(imgarray[2])){ 
traffic.src = imgarray[3];
}else if (traffic.src.match(imgarray[3])){ 
traffic.src = imgarray[0];
}}
```

Is there a way to do it without all of the if statements?

Comment: Don't tag your Javascript questions `java`.

Comment: `if` statement and array access is `O(1)` so this function is ok with performance.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace your `ChangeLights()` function to this :

```
function ChangeLights() {
    traffic.src = imgArray[imgArray.indexOf(trafficSrc) + 1 % imgArray.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var idx = 0;

function ChangeLights() { 
    idx++;
    if (idx > 2)
        idx = 0;
    traffic.src = imgarray[idx];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code boils down to this

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(ChangeLights, 2000);

function ChangeLights() {
  i = i < imgarray.length - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;
  traffic.src = imgarray[i];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i<imgarray.length; i++){
  if(traffic.src.match(imgarray[i])) {
       if(i+1 === traffic.length) {
         traffic.src = imgarray[0];
       } else {
          traffic.src = imgarray[i+1];
       }
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you made it worse.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... my bad! I did not understood the problem at first :\